# Share sheet icon on React-Native

Tags: react-native, share, react-native-ios

I've looked around everywhere I can think of and cannot for the life of me find out how to change the icon that appears in the Share sheet inside of react-native.

Is this even possible to customize?  I would love to put the app's icon in there.

[image: share icon]

Comment: Same for me ? Got any solution ?

Answer (score 4):

When using a url only, it will automatically populate this icon with your link's favicon/web icon.

For a share sheet with a custom message it doesn't seem to be supported right now but, I would love to see this in the future.

Comment: Is it still not supported? I can't find any info anywhere on how to do this.